# How to output exec to variable

Tags: php, image, svg, exec

I have this command that will convert SVG to image:

```
exec("convert -size 400x400 test.svg test.png", $out, $rcode);
```

But it works with fiels, when I actually need to work with DOM variables.

how to get the resulting PNG to $variable insted of file (in PHP) please.

Comment: You can read the resulting file or check the man page of the `convert` command for an option to write the result to stdout instead of a file.

Comment: over 3 days trying just to convert svg to png on php. All I get are clues and blured infos. Thanks anyway

Comment: Sorry, it is not our fault that you already try for 3 days. And I don't see what should be "blured" in my comment. It is pretty clear as I read it.

Comment: A straightup codeline would be much helpful. for example: $rstl = exec("xyz...")

Comment: Sorry, but StackOverflow is _not_ a code writing service.

Comment: Reading the resulting file is not an option. The images are constantly dynamiclly created for multiple users clients and should only exist for the length of the session. Doesn't make any sence to save coppies of any of them to files. It is an SVG edited on session time.

Comment: I do agree that it is not very elegant. But I do not see why it is "not an option" at all. Apart from that: you can redirect the output of the `convert` command to stdout by simply specifying a `-` (single dash) instead of the output file name. That way the result is returned and you can read it as documented for php's `exec` function.

Comment: OK, take a look at the answer below, hope that satisfies your request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably what you are looking for:

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec("convert test.svg png:-");
echo $output;
```

Depending on your local setup you might have to specify the absolute path to your `convert` utility. Also the path to the file to be converted must be resolvable, again an absolute path is a safe bet at first.

Comment: I get this results: array(0) { } and the return code shows 1. Pleas help further.

Comment: That probably means that the input image has not been found. Try using an absolute path first, to be on the safe side. Then think about what the current directory of your execution is. Oh, and I modified (simplyfied) the answer. Please check the current version :-)

Comment: It might also be that you need to specify the full path to the `convert` utility, depending on your local setup. And make sure the process actually has read permission on the file and all the folders it is contained in.

Comment: OK, you have edited your answer. The current results are NULL (for var_dump  of output)

Comment: Works for me. Must be a path or permission error on your side. I suggest you take a look into your php log file if there is a hint on what is off for you.

Comment: The codeline I entered in the main qustion does the job of converting, only problem is it reads from file and writes to file. The only change I required was the source and destination were variables instead of files.

Comment: This surprises me. Since the documentation of `convert` clearly states (and this is also what I see if I try it), that if you specify an output file name the result will be written to that file. But whatever you say. Have fun.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88943/discussion-between-israel-gav-and-arkascha).